# How to filter any special characters

Tags: php

If i have input text in form like this

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the add.php code is as following

```
$sql= "insert into mytable set myname='$txt'";
executeupdate($sql);
```

My question how to filter any text input from any special characters i just want it only `Aa-Zz-1234567890` (letters and numbers) only.

Here is my try but i'm not sure will it really filter all special characters or can pass any

i've added in add.php the following code

```
$cleared = strip_tags($txt);
$sql= "insert into mytable set myname='$cleared'";
executeupdate($sql);  // this should clear the name before insert
```

Any suggestions else or better way?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is there a requirement that your `text` only contain alphanumeric characters, even excluding space and punctuation, or for some other reason?

Comment: `strip_tags` strips tags, not non-alphanumerics. Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 $whiteSpace = '\s';  //if you dnt even want to allow white-space set it to ''
$pattern = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9'  . $whiteSpace . ']/u';
 $cleared = preg_replace($pattern, '', (string) $txt);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$txt = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $txt);
```

Also, there's nothing "special" about characters outside of the A-Z, 0-9 range.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to remove all non alpha-numeric characters:

```
$new_str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd try the following:

```
<?php
    //Replace non-alphanumerics with an "" ie nothing
    $cleared = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/i", "", $txt);
?>
```

Hope this works out for you!